# iTunes Customer reviews in XML

Tags: itunes, review, itunes-app

I want to view my app's review but I don't know some information like :

```
<entry>
 <updated>2019-07-04T06:50:17-07:00</updated>
  ...
<im:voteSum>0</im:voteSum>
<im:voteCount>0</im:voteCount>
<im:rating>5</im:rating>
<im:version>1.13</im:version>
<author>
  <name>...</name>
  <uri>...</uri>
</author>
...
</entry>
```

Please, Explain to me What is meaning of  `<im:voteSum>` and`<im:voteCount>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After parsing the data and looking on iTunes (Music on Catalina) I discovered that it's the helpful votes.

- `im:voteSum` is the number of customers who found the review helpful
- `im:voteCount` is the total number of customers who voted (Yes or No)

You can see a sample [Customer Review JSON for the New York Times](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=284862083/sortBy=mostHelpful/page=1/json).

[image: Mapping Apple App Store Review Data]

You can see these on any app when using iTunes / Music on the Mac. I don't know if these show elsewhere in the iOS App Store.

[image: Show Helpful Reviews with All Versions]